# Css / jQuery / mobile responsive - How to make my animation responsive?

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, responsive-design, gsap

I am using jQuery and tweenmax for an introduction animation but just don't know how to make it responsive.
Its on jsfiddle(link below) but the problem is

```
   webkitClipPath:'circle('+ this.coverW +' at 0 0)'
```

and I just don't know how to change it so its responsive..any help would be very much appreciated!!!

http://codepen.io/helloocoding/pen/zNQQoR

Comment: Take a look at using GSAP `xPercent` and `yPercent` special properties. see their blog page: https://greensock.com/gsap-1-13-1

Answer (score 0):

Well that seems to be quite a complex task. If I was you I'd start by styling the result of your animation on a mobile screen so you at least know in which direction you should work.